# '&' not displaying in IE & safari in a span

Tags: c#, jquery, model-view-controller

When i click in in button, the & character in the textbox is not displaying in span as i m using (also doesnt dispalys in div, p etc). I am using jQuery for the button click. I also tried to use `$.URLEncode` `$.URLDecode` but result was negative.

I will be grateful if anyone can help me.

Comment: Why would you use `URLEncode`/`URLDecode`? You're not dealing with URLs here.

Answer (score 2):

You have to use `&amp;` to encode the ampersand in HTML.

Answer (score 0):

URLEncode is not useful or relevant, as you're cleaning/escaping the output for HTML, not a URL component. Replacing `&` (which is a reserved symbol for the start of an entity) with `&amp;` would correct the problem.

Comment: well i replaced '&' with the ascii value '&#38;' and this worked pretty good anyways thanx for the suggestion, it helped me a lot.